# How to create an OCaml standalone executable in Windows

Tags: ocaml

I need to distribute the final executable of my project to students without the need for students to install and use [Cygwin-based installer of OCaml](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/). How can I do it?

Here is what I did to build the executable (skipped other commands for clarity):

```
"..\.opam\4.06.1+mingw64c\bin\ocamlc.exe" -I "..\.opam\4.06.1+mingw64c\lib\ocaml" -o compiler.exe AST.cmo Machine.cmo Compiler.cmo Grammar.cmo Lexer.cmo Main.ml
```

When I try to run `compiler.exe`, an error named **Cannot exec** occurs. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [native compiler](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/native.html) `ocamlopt` (instead of the byte compiler `ocamlc`) to compile your *entire* project.

<sup>(it is probably `ocamlopt.exe` on your system)</sup>